# Is it possible to get only initialized properties in a C# class

Tags: c#

I have a class as follows

```
public class SampleClass{

  public string Property1 {get; set;}

  public string Property2 {get; set;}

  public string Property3 {get; set;}

}
```

Then I create an initialization of this class only with two properties and send it through some method. Here, I get all the 3 properties but how can I differentiate whether the 3rd property is initialized or not while accessing within the method?.

```
var classInstance = new SampleClass {
  Property1 = "one",
  Property2 = "two"
};

this.SomeMethod(classInstance);

// Is it possible to get that the third property is not defined in the class instance in this method?
```

Comment: Write a constructor.

Comment: check if it's null(or default value) or not

Comment: When you do `new sampleClass { ... }` everything you do not set within the brackets is set by the constructor you called (the default one in your example) so the constructor will init everything else either as it's written in the constructor or with the default value for the type of the property/field

Comment: Side-note: it's worth making sample code on Stack Overflow follow regular conventions, in this case .NET naming conventions. It's distracting when code doesn't look how readers expect it to.

Comment: also stop using sock-puppet acount for upvoting your questions ... you have been flagged

Answer (score 4):

First, these are properties, not attributes. Attributes are a different language construct in C#. We've edited your question accordingly.

Second, using an object initializer as in your example with `classInstance` is equivalent to calling the default constructor, then the setter of the two first properties.

Since the default constructor is empty in your class, all 3 properties will be null after calling it. This is because `string` is a reference type, and all reference types have a default value of null. Then `Property1` will be set to "one", `Property2` to "two", and `Property3` will keep the null value.

It is not the case that `Property3` is not defined on `classInstance` . It simply has the value null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constructor and initialize properties in it. it will works fine then.

```
public class sampleClass
{
    public sampleClass(){
     this.Init();
    }

    public string property1 {get; set;}
    public string property2 {get; set;}
    public string property3 {get; set;}

    private void Init()
    {
        this.property1 = "one";
        this.property2 = "two";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you're looking for ?
A custom constructor

```
public class SampleClass
    {
        public SampleClass(string property1, string property2)
        {
            this.Property1 = property1;
            this.Property2 = property2;
            this.Property3 = null;
        }

        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        public string Property2 { get; set; }

        public string Property3 { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm not sure of what you're using it for though, but maybe if you've many different conditional use cases like this one, a class that do it all is maybe the best solution.
Let us know.